# add checkbox in gridview causes error in calculation in datatable

Tags: gridview, webforms

I've added checkbox in gridview at my web page currently right now it's make my calculation quantity * price having problem where it display on another column and row. I'm using javascript for the calculation. The checkbox is displayed but the calculation getting problem.

Before I add checkbox:[image]

After I added checkbox in my code
[image]

I'm only this using code in grid view to add checkbox

```
asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
```

This is html for my webpage

```
<asp:gridview ID="GridView1"  runat="server"  ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false">  
        <Columns>  
             <asp:TemplateField>
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />  
        <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Item Description" />  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Price">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="LBLPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity">  
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:TextBox ID="TXTQty" runat="server" onkeyup="CalculateTotals();"></asp:TextBox>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
            <FooterTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="LBLQtyTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Blue" Text="" ></asp:Label>       
                <b>Total Amount:</b>  
            </FooterTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Total">
            <ItemTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="LBLSubTotal" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>  
            </ItemTemplate>  
            <FooterTemplate>  
                <asp:Label ID="LBLTotal" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Font-Bold="true" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>  
            </FooterTemplate>  
        </asp:TemplateField>  
        </Columns>  
    </asp:gridview>
```

Code behind

```
private void BindDummyDataToGrid()
        {

            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            DataRow dr = null;

            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
            dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(string)));

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
            dr["Description"] = "Nike";
            dr["Price"] = "1000";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 2;
            dr["Description"] = "Converse";
            dr["Price"] = "800";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 3;
            dr["Description"] = "Adidas";
            dr["Price"] = "500";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 4;
            dr["Description"] = "Reebok";
            dr["Price"] = "750";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 5;
            dr["Description"] = "Vans";
            dr["Price"] = "1100";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);

            dr = dt.NewRow();
            dr["RowNumber"] = 6;
            dr["Description"] = "Fila";
            dr["Price"] = "200";
            dt.Rows.Add(dr);
            //Bind the GridView  
            GridView1.DataSource = dt;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
            {
                BindDummyDataToGrid();
            }
        }
    }
```

Whle debugging it doesn't have show any error regarding my code. I've searched about this but still didn't find any source that related with what I need.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't show your java

So, this makrup + java should work:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"
            CssClass="table" Width="40%">
            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox1" runat="server" />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="RowNumber" HeaderText="Row Number" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Item Description" />
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Item Price" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" ItemStyle-Width="90px">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBLPrice" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Price","{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Quantity"
                    ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center" ItemStyle-Width="120"
                    FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="TXTQty" runat="server" onchange="CalculateTotals(this);"
                            Width="50px" Style="text-align: right" Text='<%# Eval("Qty") %>'></asp:TextBox>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBLQtyTotal" runat="server" Font-Bold="true" ForeColor="Blue" Text=""></asp:Label>
                        <b>Total Amount:</b>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Sub-Total" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right" FooterStyle-HorizontalAlign="Right"
                    ControlStyle-Width="60">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBLSubTotal" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Text='<%# Eval("SubTotal","{0:C}") %>'></asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <FooterTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="LBLTotal" runat="server" ForeColor="Green" Font-Bold="true" Text="0.00"></asp:Label>
                    </FooterTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>

        <script>

            function CalculateTotals(ctl) {
                var Qty = $('#' + ctl.id)
                var Price = $('#' + ctl.id.replace('TXTQty', 'LBLPrice'))
                var tAmount = $('#' + ctl.id.replace('TXTQty', 'LBLSubTotal'))

                var n = Qty.val() * fCurrencyToNum(Price.text())
                tAmount.text(ftoCurrency((n)))

                GrandTotal()

            }

            function GrandTotal() {

                var MyTotal = 0.0
                var rowCount = $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> tr").length;
                rowCount = rowCount - 2 // remove header row, and footer from count

                for (var iRow = 0; iRow < rowCount; iRow++) {
                    tAmount = $('#GridView1_LBLSubTotal_' + iRow)
                    MyTotal = MyTotal + + fCurrencyToNum(tAmount.text())
                }
                $('#GridView1_LBLTotal').text(ftoCurrency(MyTotal))

            }

        </script>
```

And now your code behind:

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            BindDummyDataToGrid();
            // call client side Grand total code
            string strJava = "GrandTotal()";

            ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Page, Page.GetType(), "myjava", strJava, true);

        }

    }

    private void BindDummyDataToGrid()
    {

        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        DataRow dr = null;

        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("RowNumber", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Description", typeof(string)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Price", typeof(decimal)));
        dt.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("Qty", typeof(int)));
        DataColumn SubTotal = new DataColumn("SubTotal",typeof(decimal));
        SubTotal.Expression = " [Price] * [Qty]";
        dt.Columns.Add(SubTotal);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 1;
        dr["Description"] = "Nike";
        dr["Price"] = "1000";
        dr["Qty"] = "1";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 2;
        dr["Description"] = "Converse";
        dr["Price"] = "800";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 3;
        dr["Description"] = "Adidas";
        dr["Price"] = "500";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 4;
        dr["Description"] = "Reebok";
        dr["Price"] = "750";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 5;
        dr["Description"] = "Vans";
        dr["Price"] = "1100";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);

        dr = dt.NewRow();
        dr["RowNumber"] = 6;
        dr["Description"] = "Fila";
        dr["Price"] = "200";
        dt.Rows.Add(dr);
        //Bind the GridView  
        GridView1.DataSource = dt;
        GridView1.DataBind();
    }
```

Note how I added a column in the data table that calculates the row total. You don't need this, but if you start to include a Qty in the datatable, then it will automatic calculate the row total for you.

So, the result is now this:

[image]

I have assumed  you have jQuery installed (you most likely do). And I used the bootstrap CssCalss="table" to make the grid look a whole lot nicer. (you have to add width=40% or whatever, since with the CssCalss="table", then it will default to the full width of the screen without width (it actually becomes a responsive grid view when you do this).

## Edit: User suggests they don't have jquery installed

Ok, then just put this right before the gv

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.6.3.min.js"></script>

<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" ShowFooter="true" AutoGenerateColumns="false"

 bla bla bla - the rest of the gv here
```

Comment: I tried the method you give me but when I add quantity in textbox it doesn't show the answer perhaps because I don't have jquery

Comment: the javascript is i'm using example from https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1112018/How-To-Do-Calculations-in-GridView-2

Comment: See my edit - just add jQuery then.  I can't imagine that jQuery not already part of your project - it been a "defaulted" library for just about any web forms template for about 10 years now. Anyway, just add the above one line and use jQuery via what we call CDN. So, adding that one script reference should do the trick. And the post code does work, and note HOW VERY little JavaScript code was written.